# cost explorer ec2 usage data filter conditions causing botocore error

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cost-explorer

Ive been trying to get usage data for Ec2 instances for all user values tagged as 'User'. Idk what im doing wrong but i keep getting some type of botocore error.
I can't figure out what is wrong with the filter. Appreciate any help

```
for value in tag_values:
    response = ce_client.get_cost_and_usage(
        TimePeriod={'Start': '2023-05-05', 'End': '2023-10-10'},
        Granularity='MONTHLY',
        Metrics=['UsageQuantity'],  # blendedcost
        Filter={
            'Tags': {
                'Key': 'User',
                'Values': [value]
            },
            'Dimensions': {'Key': 'SERVICE', 
             'Values': ['Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute']
             }
        }    
    )
```

error in this line->

```
response = ce_client.get_cost_and_usage(
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetCostAndUsage operation: Expression has more than one roots. Only one root operator is allowed for each expression: And, Or, Not, Dimensions, Tags, CostCategories
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine your filters with an operator, e.g. using `And`:

```py
ce_client = boto3.client("ce")
for value in tag_values:
    response = ce_client.get_cost_and_usage(
        TimePeriod={"Start": "2023-05-05", "End": "2023-10-10"},
        Granularity="MONTHLY",
        Metrics=["UsageQuantity"],  # blendedcost
        Filter={
            "And": [
                {
                    "Tags": {"Key": "User", "Values": [value]},
                },
                {
                    "Dimensions": {
                        "Key": "SERVICE",
                        "Values": ["Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute"],
                    },
                },
            ]
        },
    )
```